# What exception type should I raise if my dictionary is missing required keys?

Tags: python, django

I am testing that `data` (dictionary), used in *Django's* `render(request, url, data)`, has some required keys. I will raise an exception if the required keys are missing. What exception type is best suited for this?

Is there a better way to think about this?

Comment: Maybe a [`KeyError`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError) will fit your needs.

Comment: What is wrong with `KeyError`? Moreover python will do the job of throwing the exception. You need to catch it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with `KeyError`. I was stuck thinking about it differently and I couldn't see the obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For consistency with regular dicts, I would think a `KeyError` would be appropriate

```
>>> d = {'foo': 'bar'}
>>> d[5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    d[5]
KeyError: 5
```

[`KeyError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError)

> Raised when a mapping (dictionary) key is not found in the set of existing keys.